# Zeros of inverse of dilogarithm

Tags: nt.number-theory, power-series

I was thinking about how the standard proofs that $\pi$ is irrational use variations on $sin(\pi) =0$, in contrast to Apéry's proofs that $\zeta(2),\zeta(3)$ are irrational (the first of course also proving that $\pi$ is irrational.)

My question is as follows:

Let
$$Li_2(x)=\sum_{n\ge1} \frac{x^n}{n^2},$$

and let $f(x)$ denote its compositional inverse.

What are the complex roots of $f$?

I didn't find anything looking around, and playing with sage makes it look like maybe there are no zeros.

Comment: I have no idea whether it helps, but it is at least fun - the compositional inverse satisfies a relatively nice differential equation: $x^{3} f'\left(x\right)^{3} + {\left(x + 1\right)} f\left(x\right)^{3} + 3 \, x f\left(x\right)^{2} f'\left(x\right) - {\left(x^{2} - {\left(x^{3} + 3 \, x^{2}\right)} f\left(x\right)\right)} f'\left(x\right)^{2} - f\left(x\right)^{2} - {\left(x^{3} f\left(x\right)^{2} - x^{2} f\left(x\right)\right)} f''\left(x\right) = 0$

Comment: what do you mean by compositional inverse and also by $Li_2$ (in the sense that $Li_2$ is a multivalued function with branch points at $1, \infty$ so do you think of $Li_2$ as defined on say the complex plane minus $[1,\infty]$ as the "main branch" or something else?

Comment: I think that the answer is: the integer multiples of $4\pi^2$.

Comment: That is, the numbers that arise as values of the multi-valued function $Li_2(x)$ at $x=0$ are precisely the numbewrs $4\pi^2k$, $k\in\mathbb Z$.

Comment: @Conrad : the compositional inverse can be defined from the power series, and I don't think it's a multivalued function. This is similar to log being multivalued but exp is not.

Comment: @TomGoodwillie : that's what I would hope for. Can this be proved?

Comment: @HenriCohen : nah, try increasing truncation degree and you'll see that zero disappear

Comment: @DrorSpeiser : If it's true then I think you can find it in https://arxiv.org/abs/alg-geom/9202022 (section 2, Monodromy).